# Playboy (SciFi) short story from the 1980s

Tags: story-identification

This was a story published in Playboy Magazine in the 1980s.

An intergalactic art dealer is attracted to beautiful alien. When they make love, the climax is a glimpse of her inner being & the world she is from.

Comment: are you saying the story was in a Playboy magazine?

Comment: @Skooba - The Capitalisation of the letter P (in the title) would strongly suggest so.

Comment: @Valorum:  ...and then you promptly edit to ambiguate the conspicuous capital by moving it to the beginning of the title...

Comment: @ThePopMachine - It seems pretty unambiguous to me. Playboy has been a [famous publisher of scifi short stories](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Playboy-Book-Science-Fiction/dp/0061073423) for decades.

Comment: @Valorum:   I was just pointing out that you called attention to the capital P and then undid the information conveyed by it.   Just a friendly poke.

Answer (score 8):

Could this be "[Tourist Trade](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Multiples-Collected-Stories-Robert-Silverberg/dp/1596064021)" by Robert Silverberg (December 1984, Playboy)?

> Eitel is an art dealer who is selling a Renaissance painting to
>   collectors from Centauras. His price was four million, but he offers a
>   special deal when he sees the lady Centauran.

---

> *In that bleak moment came a surprise. For as he shook and quivered in the force of that dismal ejaculation something opened between them, a barrier, a gate, and the hotel melted and disappeared and he saw himself in the midst of a bizarre landscape. The sky was a rich golden-green, the sun was deep green and hot, the trees and plants and flowers were like nothing he had ever seen on Earth. The air was heavy, aromatic, and of a piercing flavor that stung his nostrils.   Flying creatures that were not birds soared unhurriedly overhead, and some iridescent beasts that looked like red velvet pillows mounted on tripods were grazing on the lower branches of furry-limbed trees. On the horizon Eitel saw three jagged naked mountains of some yellow-brown stone that gleamed like polished metal in the sunlight. He trembled. Wonder and awe engulfed his spirit. **This is a park, he realized, the most beautiful park in the world. But this is not this world. He found a little path that led over a gentle hill, and when he came to the far side he looked down to see Centaurans strolling two by two, hand in hand, through an elegantly contoured garden.**
>
>   Oh, my God, Eitel thought. Oh, my God in heaven!
>
>   Then it all began to fade, growing thin, turning to something no more substantial than smoke, and in a moment more it was all gone. He lay still, breathing raggedly, by her side, watching her breasts slowly rising and falling.
>   He lifted his head. She was studying him. “You liked that?”*

Comment: OP's description made me think of "The Soul Painter and the Shapeshifter", also by Silverberg, but I believe that was published in Omni rather than Playboy.